# Error in Values v11-v14 styles After change API

Tags: android

I have been building my app in 4.2.2 and when I try to change the API level to 2.3.3 it gives me a error in vaules v11,v14. I want to change it to 2.3.3 so It can work for more phones models.

```
  <resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

 </resources>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error and tell me how it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change the minimum API to work with Android 2.3 and leave target API as it was, e.g. to support 2.3 at the minimum and target 4.4, you should use:

```
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

You should also build against Android 4.4 in this case.

Application will be available for devices with Android 2.3 but you will obviously need to make sure it works on them.

Comment: This Is what I done, right clicked my project changed it to 2.3.3 from 4.2. changed my manifest to what u said error is still there. if I leave as 4.2.2 and add support multiple screen it will be fine on most devices.all errors go when i change it back.

Comment: Don't change it to 2.3.3 on the project though. You need to compile against 4.2.

Comment: ok. I think Iv not really understand the backward compatibility. So am I right in thinking if i build a app in 4.4 it will be backward compatibility.That's if I add multiple support screens to layout.

Comment: Yes, it's best to build against the latest. Then you can still support lower versions while taking advantage of new ones, e.g. defining different layouts for v11 and v14. The compiler will tell you if you're using something that was not there in lower versions. You still need to test on lower version devices though.

Comment: Thank you. Yes At the moment am testing my app on my friends phone 2.3.6 I will be sure to text it on many versions. Just missed this part at the beginning when I started it. Thanks again..